# Nullpointerexception at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.<c linit>(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:57)

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception, spring-data-mongodb

As I have looked for an answer to this exception, but didn't find it anywhere, I'll leave this post here for future reference. So if anyone else runs into this problem, you are welcome.

I'm using the `maven shade plugin` to create a runnable jar together with `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.4.0.RELEASE`

I was running into the exception in the title, after creating the jar and running it with `java -jar Foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer:

The error is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/DefaultDbRefResolver.java
in this line:

```
private static final boolean IS_SPRING_4_OR_BETTER = SpringVersion.getVersion().startsWith("4");
```

`SpringVersion.getVersion` returns null if it cannot retrieve the version number from the package. As the dependencies are extracted in the shaded jar, there is no package to retrieve the version number from and `.startsWith("4")` throws a `NullPointerException`.

To solve this issue (well it's kind of a quick and dirty solution, but it works), create a package `org.springframework.core` in your source folder and create the following class (I am using the springframework in version 4.0.2-RELEASE):

```
package org.springframework.core;

/**
 * for spring data mongodb
 * it can't determine the springversion in the shaded jar
 */
public class SpringVersion {
    public static String getVersion() {
        return "4.0.2-RELEASE";
    }

}
```

The class will overwrite the original `SpringVersion` class file.

Comment: Thank you so much for you solution.
This is soooooo stupid that the logic is depending on a package version number!

Answer (score 1):

Like @mininme mentioned in his answer, the problem arises in `4.0.2.RELEASE` because of

```
SpringVersion.getVersion().startsWith("4").
```

For now it means, that if you have such a problem, you should probably try a more recent version of Spring. At version `4.3.0.RELEASE` of Spring there in no such problem anymore.