# Unable to initialize mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb in my application. This is a standalone gradle based project. This is my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
    >

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.standalone"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="testdb" />

<bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
</bean>

<bean id="mongoDbFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoClient"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mobpulse"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactoryBean" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

In my main class I initialize the context:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

I get an error saying `mongoTemplate` could not be initialized. I'm using `spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE` and `spring-data-mongodb:1.5.0.RELEASE`. I'm using the same applicationContext in another web application where it works fine but in my standalone application it breaks with `Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` Any clues what may be the root cause?

This is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.sample.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1856)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:207)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.<clinit>(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:60)
... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java MongoDB drivers something wrong there,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.<clinit
```

Comment: Just got this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201136/nullpointerexception-at-org-springframework-data-mongodb-core-convert-defaultdbr where the fix is provided.